# How to use Box2D with Pixi.js

Tags: javascript, box2d, pixi.js

I've looking on the internet for this awnser, some light, where i begin.
I want to use pixi.js with box2d.js all is setted up, but i can only use b2D in "normal" canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a Box2dWeb helper in Typescript now i can use it to debug physics with Box2DWeb using any "renderer" (in my case PixiJs).
 If you want it is [here on my Github](https://github.com/WesFerreira/mon-chan).